# ¿Como puedo agregar un filtro a esta consulta sql ,para que me retorne solo las reservas activas?

Tags: mysql, sql

La tabla reserva tiene un atributo que se llama activa. DeberÍa ser algo así, como con un where activa ='1', pero al agregarlo a la consulta no me retorna nada.(revise la tabla y tengo varias reservas cargadas con 1 y 0 en el campo activa).Quizas no estoy colocando en lugar que corresponde el where.

La consulta a la que le agrege el where quedo asi , quizas estoy implementando mal el where ,
la tabla Reserva tiene el campo

- activa (INT) ---> si contiene 1 esta activa / si contiene un 0 esta desactivada

````
    "SELECT r.id
    , TRIM(CONCAT(c.nombres, ' ', c.apellidos)) AS cliente
    , e.nombre AS estado
    , e.color AS color
    , MIN(dr.inicio) AS checkin
    , MAX(dr.termino) AS checkout 
    FROM reserva r
    WHERE r.activa ='1' 
    INNER JOIN estado e ON r.id_estado = e.id 
    INNER JOIN detalle_reserva dr ON r.id = dr.id_reserva 
    INNER JOIN cliente c ON r.id_cliente = c.id 
    INNER JOIN producto p ON dr.id_producto = p.id 
    INNER JOIN servicio s ON p.id_servicio = s.id 
    WHERE CASE WHEN #{cliente} IS NULL OR #{cliente} = '' 
         THEN true ELSE c.rut = #{cliente} END 
    AND CASE WHEN #{estado} IS NULL OR #{estado} = 0 
         THEN true ELSE r.id_estado = #{estado} END 
    AND CASE WHEN #{categoria} IS NULL OR #{categoria} = 0 
         THEN true ELSE s.id_categoria = #{categoria} END 
    GROUP BY r.id
         , c.nombres 
         ,c.apellidos 
         ,e.nombre 
    HAVING CASE WHEN #{fecha} IS NULL
             THEN true 
             ELSE checkin >= CONCAT(#{fecha}, ' 00:00:00') END" ```

pero me arroja el siguiente error:Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 



**La consulta Actual que funciona pero me retorna todas las reserva y no solo las que esta activa ,es esta: **
------------------------------------------------------------------------

     "SELECT r.id,
TRIM(CONCAT(c.nombres, ' ', c.apellidos)) AS cliente
, e.nombre AS estado
, e.color AS color
, MIN(dr.inicio) AS checkin
, MAX(dr.termino) AS checkout 
FROM reserva r
INNER JOIN estado e ON r.id_estado = e.id 
INNER JOIN detalle_reserva dr ON r.id = dr.id_reserva 
INNER JOIN cliente c ON r.id_cliente = c.id 
INNER JOIN producto p ON dr.id_producto = p.id 
INNER JOIN servicio s ON p.id_servicio = s.id 
WHERE CASE WHEN #{cliente} IS NULL OR #{cliente} = '' 
    THEN true ELSE c.rut = #{cliente} END 
AND CASE WHEN #{estado} IS NULL OR #{estado} = 0 
    THEN true ELSE r.id_estado = #{estado} END 
AND CASE WHEN #{categoria} IS NULL OR #{categoria} = 0 
    THEN true ELSE s.id_categoria = #{categoria} END
 GROUP BY r.id
    , c.nombres
    , c.apellidos
    , e.nombre 
HAVING CASE WHEN #{fecha} IS NULL 
    THEN true 
    ELSE checkin >= CONCAT(#{fecha}, ' 00:00:00') END"



---

**La consulta Actual que funciona pero me retorna todas las reserva y no solo las que esta activa ,es esta:  

 ` "SELECT r.id, TRIM(CONCAT(c.nombres, ' ', c.apellidos)) AS cliente, e.nombre AS estado, e.color AS color, MIN(dr.inicio) AS checkin, MAX(dr.termino) AS checkout FROM reserva r INNER JOIN estado e ON r.id_estado = e.id INNER JOIN detalle_reserva dr ON r.id = dr.id_reserva INNER JOIN cliente c ON r.id_cliente = c.id INNER JOIN producto p ON dr.id_producto = p.id INNER JOIN servicio s ON p.id_servicio = s.id WHERE CASE WHEN #{cliente} IS NULL OR #{cliente} = '' THEN true ELSE c.rut = #{cliente} END AND CASE WHEN #{estado} IS NULL OR #{estado} = 0 THEN true ELSE r.id_estado = #{estado} END AND CASE WHEN #{categoria} IS NULL OR #{categoria} = 0 THEN true ELSE s.id_categoria = #{categoria} END GROUP BY r.id, c.nombres, c.apellidos, e.nombre HAVING CASE WHEN #{fecha} IS NULL THEN true ELSE checkin >= CONCAT(#{fecha}, ' 00:00:00') END"`
````

Comment: Bienvenido NachoR a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Si al usar `r.activa` te deja de retornar resultados puede ser que: **1.** No tienes ninguna reserva con el valor filtrado o **2.** No existe el valor '1' para el campo `r.activa`. Te sugiero hacer un `select distinct r.activa from reserva r` para verificar el valor exacto que debe usar en el filtro where. Bienvenido a Stackoverflow

Comment: mira quizas es donde este implementando el where , haber si me puedes corregir , pondre la consulta como la estaba usando porque me marca error de sintaxy

Comment: Deberías mover la condición del `WHERE r.activa ='1'` al final de la consulta, antes del `GROUP BY r.id`, junto al resto de condiciones del `WHERE` principal. El error que te está dando es muy probable que esté saliendo por tener un `INNER JOIN` después de un `WHERE`.

Comment: No cortes el mensaje de error. Ese mensaje de error que estás poniendo incompleto suele decir exactamente dónde está el error de sintaxis...